# display type BLOB as a link

Tags: php, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I want to display records in the website and the $row['data'] of the table report its type (BLOB) in a database and I want to display it as a link but it doesn't appear anymore.

What Can I do ? Whats the problem here?

```
            <?php
        include 'connect.php';
        extract($_SESSION);
        session_start();
             ?>

         <html>

             <body >
             <table>

        <?php   


            $sql="SELECT data,report.StudID,studFName,StudLName
            FROM report,student
           WHERE report.SuperID={$_SESSION['supervisor']} AND 
             report.StudID=student.StudID ";

        $result= mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("could not found; 
        ".mysqli_error($con));


       while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
         {
               ?>
          <tr>  


   <td><?php echo '<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($row ['data']).' " height="20" width="20" />'?></td>

     <td><?php echo $row['StudLName'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['studFName'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['StudID'] ?></td>


                   <?php
                       } 
                     ?>
                 </tr>

              </table>
```

Comment: what doesn't appear ? link or pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

Your link won't appear because you need to enclose it with `</a>` and specify text in it.

```
<?php 
echo '<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($row ['data']).' " />Pdf Link</a>'
?>
```

I don't think you need to specify `height` and `width` for link.